# Characteristic function of symmetric distribution

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I know that if $X$ is a symmetric random variable, then the characteristic function is real, since $\overline{E[e^{itX}]} = E[e^{-itX}]=E[e^{itX}]$. However, is there a simple way (without appealing to some sort of inversion) to show the converse? (If the characteristic function of a distribution is real, then the distribution is symmetric.)

Comment: What makes you think that the proof is not just doing the same idea in reverse?

Comment: @Chappers In order to claim $E[e^{-itX}]=E[e^{itX}]$ implies $X \overset{d}{=} -X$, we need the uniqueness of characteristic functions, and I was wondering if there was a way to avoid using that strong result.

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that you could do so without having the uniqueness theorem: how would you know that doing a unique manipulation of any sort to the characteristic function would produce a corresponding unique manipulation of the distribution otherwise?